# Play video if the modal is open and if the Bootstrap carousel in the modal's first carousel item is video

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have multiple modals and all of them have a Bootstrap 4 carousel which has mix of videos and images. I am looking to auto play the video if the first carousel item has video. Everything is working fine except that I cannot pause the video using built-in pause control of the video. Video pauses for a moment and starts playing again. Below is the code I tried so far -

```
$(document).ready(function() {

                

                function showModalAlert() {
                    setInterval(function() {

                        
                        var firstSlide = $('#LegacyModal #custCarousel1 .carousel-inner').find('.carousel-item').first();

                        // alert(firstSlide.hasClass('active'));


                        var video = document.getElementById("LegacyVideo");
                        

                        if (firstSlide.hasClass('active') && ($('#LegacyModal').hasClass('show'))) {
                            // console.log(video)

                            if (video && video.paused) {
                                video.play();
                                console.log("Video played");
                            }
                        }

                        else {
                            
                             // Check if the video is playing before pausing it
                            if (video && !video.paused) {
                                video.pause();
                                console.log("Video paused");
                            }  
                        }
                    }, 1000);

                }

                $("#LegacyModal").on("show.bs.modal", showModalAlert);
                
                
            });
```